# Azure Servicebus - get all available topics in python

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Azure Servicebus and want to retrieve all topics that are available based on my connection string.

In the Microsoft docs I was able to see that there is a ["GetTopics" function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.gettopics?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_GetTopics) for C# - is there something similar available within the Python SDK? I cant find anything in the source code of the [azure-sdk-for-python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/search?q=gettopics)....

```
CONNECTION_STR = "XXX"
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)
servicebus_client.gettopics() # function does not exist in Python
```

Clarification: I do not know the topic names and want to know which ones are available at the ServiceBusClient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`list_topics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.management.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-python#list-topics---kwargs-) in [`ServiceBusAdministrationClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.management.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-python) class.

Here's the sample code taken from [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/mgmt_topic.py):

```
import os
import uuid
import datetime
from azure.servicebus.management import ServiceBusAdministrationClient

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STR']

def list_topics(servicebus_mgmt_client):
    print("-- List Topics")
    for topic_properties in servicebus_mgmt_client.list_topics():
        print("Topic Name:", topic_properties.name)
    print("")

with ServiceBusAdministrationClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STR) as servicebus_mgmt_client:
    list_topics(servicebus_mgmt_client)
```